# How to comment all lines in region

Tags: emacs

Emacs tries to be clever with its comment functions so that lines which are blank don't get a comment prefix. Is there an easy built in way to make sure that all lines (blank or not) get commented when I call something like `comment-region`? So, if I have this code:

```
Comment comment comment

More comments more comments
```

Suppose the comment prefix is `//`, I want to be able to select that region, and have the comments look like:

```
// Comment comment comment
// 
// More comments more comments
```

Yes, I could write a custom function to do this, but it seems like basic enough behavior that it might somehow be built in.

Comment: For other ways to accomplish this (without using `comment-region`), see [this question](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/11/11).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> `comment-empty-lines` is a variable defined in `newcomment.el`.
>   Its value is nil
>
> Documentation:
>   If nil, `comment-region` does not comment out empty lines.
>   If t, it always comments out empty lines.
>   If `eol` it only comments out empty lines if comments are
>   terminated by the end of line (i.e. `comment-end` is empty).
>
> You can customize this variable.

Comment: Probably should have been able to find this myself, but thanks so much for taking the time to answer!